# Can metamaterial works for ultra short pulses?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, metamaterials

I have read little bit about metamaterials and understand that one can create new structure such that some of characteristic of usual elctromagnetic behaviour can be altered while propagating through the structure. Most of the literature talks about effect of different frequencies of the wave while passing through the structure. I am interested to know if short pulses are allowed to pass will it have the same behaviour? In some I a want to know if there id a transient characteristic of metamaterial. Any comment would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **guess** you're asking about the following, but unfortunately it is not 100% clear.

Metamaterials (in optics) are basically systems, the optical properties of which (such as dielectric function) cannot be simply inferred from those properties of their constituents. This holds at certain optical frequencies, or rather within limited frequency ranges. When you compress an optical pulse, its spectral width increases. So basically as long as the spectrum of your short pulse fits within the "active" spectral range of a metamaterial, the answer is yes. If you keep reducing the pulse duration, at some point it will break.